# angular2 openlayers on click map show details

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, onclick, openlayers-3

In angular2 component, in ngOnInit, I want to take the element id on  openlayers map click. This is my code:

```
map.on("click", (e)=> {
    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, function (feature, layer) {
        let id: number=feature.getId();
        this.myService.getFeatureDetail(id)
          .suscribe(data => this.myArray = data)
    })
});
```

but when I click on map I get an error that I can't call the function 'getFeatureDetail' of undefined, I tried also to save id on a global variable but it doesn't resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use arrow function (=>) instead of typing function. It lexically captures the meaning of this.

```
 map.on("click", (e) => {
     map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, (feature, layer) => {
         ...
     }) 
 });
```

Comment: I think you have to extend your answer and to explain why your solution works and what's the difference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is,, that you're losing value of `this` into your callback scope, because it's referring to another object, that has no instance of `myService`.

If you will save your reference to your advice object into another variable (`_this` or `self` or `me` etc), it can use that variable later.

Follow [this link](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/javascript-variable-scope-this/) for more details

```
map.on("click", (e)=> {
        var _this = this;
        map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, function (feature, layer) {
            let id: number=feature.getId();
            _this.myService.getFeatureDetail(id)
              .suscribe(data => this.myArray = data)
        })
    });
```

@Fatal's answer works because Lambda (Fat arrow) function does exactly the same (If it's compiled into `ES5`), and YES, it's the most comfortable approach for this case.

BUT knowing what's happening behind scenes is crucial for some situations.

Please also read this (2 min read) [article](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/arrow-functions.html#tip-arrow-function-danger).